# reactive data base server

Tags: javascript, database, relational-database, reactive-programming

I am looking for 'reactive database', but unfortunately I am not sure that I call it correctly. What I want is the database server, having following properties. I will represent record as JavaScript objects, but only for demonstration, schema-less is not required.

1. Records (aka rows) are able to store the functions:

   ```
   { "id": 1234,
   "name": "cube",
   "material": "steel",
   "volume": 2.0,
   "weight": function() { return this.volume * 8; } }
   ```

   User must be provided with the value 16.0, when asking "weight". Indexes (if exist) also must be modified accordingly. Nothing special here, it is redundant and can be implemented with conventional SQL trigger functions.
2. Functions can have other objects in their scope. Let me have a collection (aka table) 'materials' with the record:

   ```
   { "name": "steel", "density": 8 }
   ```

   then example is transformed as:

   ```
   { "id": 1234,
   "name": "cube",
   "material": "steel",
   "volume": 2.0,
   "weight": function() { return this.volume * materials[this.material].density; } }
   ```

   And I want the database to recalculate the value of "weight" (and all other fields referring to `materials["steel"].density`), when steel record is updated. This is way harder to achieve using ordinary SQL triggers. But this behavior may be called push-reactive.
3. Functions with arity can be transferred to user. Consider the following collection of the quantum mechanics systems.

   ```
   { "name": "QHO",
     "angular_frequency": 42,
     "energy": function(n) {return this.angular_frequency*1.054*(n+1/2);}
   },
   { "name": "particle_in_a_box",
     "length": 20,
     "mass": 1,
     "energy": function(n) {return (1.054*3.14)**2 * n**2 / (2*this.mass*this.length) ;}
   }
   ```

   Then "energy" must be returned as a closure, carrying all referred variables.
4. Notifications should be generated for user (when required) when recalculation of the specified field happens.

Could you please point me, if there is something ready?